# how to use Facebook share button in my web page to share or post something to facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am added a facebook share button to my website it is sharing or posting things to profile timelines but it is not sharing or posting anything to my page(like fans page in facebook).Is there anyway to choose to post to your fan page? any one can help me? plz..

Answer (score 1):

Considering whatever is the "things" in your website, say a product with id 123, for example.

You can make users like it/share it using the standard [fb-like button.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
When they do like it and/or share it, it comes up as a thing they liked on your website. If that object of yours, has a proper URL with proper meta-tags, it will show up nicely on FB as a story. Good guide [here](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags)

You can also use the facebook debug tool for testing if the sharing, meta tags are all working as expected [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

If you want your page to be the object of sharing, the only thing that can be done is users can like your page from your website. You cannot share stories from the API to the page, as the page is not an entity. Meaning its not a user.

So, if the page said,

`User XYZ liked item ABC on yourwebsite.com`

it won't make much sense to the people who see this.

Instead if `userXYZ` liked an `itemABC` on your site, the following update on FB will make much more sense.

`UserXYZ liked itemABC on yourwebsite.com`
(This will have a proper pictorial representation and a clickable link to your website if the like button and the destination url are configured correctly)